# UDP connections in Julia

Tags: julia, udp

```
using Sockets
sock = UDPSocket()
bind(sock,ip"x.x.x.x",port)
```

I am new to Sockets.jl and when I run this code in the REPL, the bind() function returns "false". Does anyone know what this means? I'm sure I have the right IP and port#. There isn't much documentation for the Sockets.jl package.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the Sockets.jl code, `bind` returns false only if one of these three errors occurs:

- **UV_EACCES**
  =   permission denied
- **UV_EADDRINUSE**
  =  address already in use
- **UV_EADDRNOTAVAIL**
  =  address not available

Do you have a firewall that might be blocking UDP access? If you're sure about the IP address being correct, then `UV_EACCES` seems like the most likely reason for failure here.

Comment: I don't think a firewall is blocking access, I got `bind` to return true once but was unable to reproduce my results

Comment: If you have access to Python, can you try `import socket as s` `st = s.socket(type=s.SOCK_DGRAM)` `st.bind(("<yourIPhere>", <yourportnumber>))` and see if that raises an error? Or a similar socket bind in any other language you're familiar with.

Comment: (those are three separate lines of code, just to be clear)

Comment: I tried your python code and it worked without errors.